# Is P finitely additive when P(A) = 0 if A is Finite?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Would the answer to the exercise below be "No"? As you would have **P**(A∪B) = **P**(B) because **P**(A) = 0 if A is finite.

Suppose that Ω = **N** is the set of positive integers, and **P** is defined for all A ⊆ Ω by **P**(A) = 0 if A is finite, and **P**(A) = 1 if A is infinite. Is **P** finitely additive?

Comment: Take a couple of disjoint infinite subsets, say A, and B, then their union is still just an infinite set (thus of measure 1), but what about the sum of their individual measures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, take the set of odd natural numbers and even ones
 $$A = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{ 2n+1 \} $$
$$B = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{ 2n \} $$

they are both infinite sets hence $\mathbb{P}(A)  = \mathbb{P}(B) = 1$.But 
$\mathbb{N} = A\cup B$ and  $A\cap B = \emptyset$.

while

$$1 = \mathbb{P}\big( \mathbb{N} \big) \neq 2 =\mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) $$