# Is function P infinitely additive (countably or uncountably additive)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Suppose our probability space $W$ is the set $\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,\dots\}$ of natural numbers, and $\mathcal{A}$ is the algebra of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.
>   Suppose we define a function $P$ on $\mathcal{A}$ such that $P(X) = 0$ whenever $X\in\mathcal{A}$ is finite, and $P(X) = 1$ when $X$ is infinite.
>   Is $P$ finitely additive?
>   Either prove it is, or explain why it is not.

Where do I start with this proof? I'm new to probability, and could use a solid hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
1=P(\mathbb N) = P\left( \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} \{n\} \right) \overset{\Large\text{?}} = \sum_{n\,\in\,\mathbb N} P(\{n\}) = \sum_{n\,\in\,\mathbb N} 0 = 0. \\ \phantom{\frac11}
$$

\begin{align}
1 & = P(\mathbb N) = P( \text{set of all even members of } \mathbb N \cup \text{set of all odd members of } \mathbb N) \\[10pt]
& \overset{\Large\text{?}} = P( \text{set of all even members of } \mathbb N) + P(\text{set of all odd members of } \mathbb N) = 1+1
\end{align}

Comment: @PrasunBiswas: Do you agree w this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705285/is-p-finitely-additive-when-pa-0-if-a-is-finite

Comment: Hi Michael, I am still stuck after many days. Can you explain above? So to prove that P is infinitely additive I only need to disprove that P is finitely additive? But I don't understand what you did above.

Comment: @floatingkrishna : You cannot prove that a set function is countably additive by proving only that it is finitely additive. But you can prove that it is _not_ countably additive by proving that it is _not_ finitely additive.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: odd naturals, even naturals, naturals.

Comment: Thanks Anonymous, let me think about this, am new to probability

Comment: @tozhello don't think about probability. Think about P as a generic function on sets. The property that it must have to be finitely additive is that if you take a finite number (in this case two suffices) of disjoint sets, the sum of the values of P on them equal the value of P on their union.

Comment: Thanks, let me think.

Comment: Just to clarify: By proving P is finitely additive it is sufficient to prove that P is infinitely additive?

Comment: @tozhello I'm not sure what you mean, but try to *disprove* that P is finitely additive. Note that you only need to find *one* counterexample, instead of proving a property for an infinite number of cases.

Comment: So by using odd and even natural numbers and making them 1 + 1 = 2 this disproves that P is finitely additive & therefore proves that P is infinitely additive? I'm still lost with this question. Is there anyway you can explain this out a bit more?